# How can I save a file using encoding UTF-16-BE with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, character-encoding, utf-16

I am working with a Pandas dataframe and I need to save it into a file with an encoding type I have never used: UTF-16-BE. I understood that this encoding is not the "standard" UTF-16, which is managed by Python read/write functions.

That is what I found in another question:

- The `BE` variant is definitely big-endian; the high-order byte is
  encoded first. As with the LE variant, no BOM is permitted, so an
  initial character U+FEFF is a zero-width no-break space.

I definitely don't know how to save this file using this encoding.
Some tips?
Thank you

Comment: Specify `encoding='utf-16be'`. No BOM will be written.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your reply.
You mean a simple:
df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-16be') ?

Comment: Yes, if that is the API you are using.  You should update your question with an [mcve] that writes the file you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment about using `pandas` and `df.to_csv` here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame([['dog','狗'],['cat','猫']],columns=['English','中文'])
df.to_csv('out.csv',encoding='utf-16be',index=False)

# Verification
with open('out.csv','r',encoding='utf-16be') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for line in r:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
['English', '中文']
['dog', '狗']
['cat', '猫']
```

Hexdump of `out.csv` showing no BOM (FE FF) and big-endian data:

[image: hexdump of out.csv]

References:

- [Python Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)
- [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)